# Conflate sets of pandas columns into a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
n  objects id  x  y  Vx Vy id.1 x.1 ... Vx.40 Vy.40 ...
0     41    1  2  3  4  5   17   3  ...   5    6    ...
1     21    1  2  3  4  5   17   3  ...   0    0    ...
2     36    1  2  3  4  5   17   3  ...   0    0    ...
```

My goal is to conflate the contents of every set of id, x, y, Vx, and Vy columns into a single column.
I.e. the end result should look like this:

```
n  objects  object_0     object_1         object_40 ...
0     41   [1,2,3,4,5]  [17,3,...]  ...   [...5,6]  ...
1     21   [1,2,3,4,5]  [17,3,...]  ...   [...0,0]  ...
2     36   [1,2,3,4,5]  [17,3,...]  ...   [...0,0]  ...
```

I am kind of at a loss as to how to achieve that. My only idea was hardcoding it like

```
df['object_0'] = df[['id', 'x', 'y', 'Vx', 'Vy']].values.tolist()
df.drop(['id', 'x', 'y', 'Vx', 'Vy'], inplace=True)
for i in range(1,41):
  df[f'object_{i}'] = df[[f'id.{i}', f'x.{i}', f'y.{i}', f'Vx.{i}', f'Vy.{i}']].values.tolist()
  df.drop([f'id.{i}', f'x.{i}', f'y.{i}', f'Vx.{i}', f'Vy.{i}'], inplace=True)
```

but that is not a good option, as the number (and names) of repeating columns varies between dataframes. What is consistent is that the number of objects per row is listed, and every object has the same number of elements (i.e. there are no cases of columns going like id.26, y.26, Vx.26, id.27 Vy.27, id.28...)

I suppose I could find the number of objects via something like

```
last_obj = max([ int(col.split('.')[-1]) for col in df.columns ])
```

and then dig out the number and names of cols per object by

```
[ col.split('.')[0] for col in df.columns if col.split('.')[-1] == last_obj ]
```

but at that point this all starts seeming a bit too cluttered and hacky.

Is there a cleaner way to do that, one that works irrespective of the number of objects, of columns per object, and (ideally) of column names? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
This does work, but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

```py
last_obj = max([ int(col.split('.')[-1]) for col in df.columns if '.' in col])
obj_col_names = [ col.split('.')[0] for col in df.columns if col.split('.')[-1] == str(last_obj) ]
df['object_0'] = df[obj_col_names].values.tolist()
df.drop(obj_col_names, axis=1, inplace=True)
for i in range(1, last_obj+1):
  current_col_set = [ "".join([col, f'.{i}']) for col in obj_col_names ]
  df[f'object_{i}'] = df[current_col_set].values.tolist()
  df.drop(current_col_set, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution renames the columns into same-named groups.  Then does a groupby on those columns and converts them into lists.

**Starting with**

```
   n  objects  id  x  y  Vx  Vy  id.1  x.1  y.1  Vx.1  Vy.1
0  0       41   1  2  3   4   5    17    3    3     4     5
1  1       21   1  2  3   4   5    17    3    3     4     5
2  2       36   1  2  3   4   5    17    3    3     4     5
```

**Then**

```
nb_cols = df.shape[1]-2
nb_groups = int(df.columns[-1].split('.')[1])+1
cols_per_group = nb_cols // nb_groups
group_cols = np.arange(nb_cols)//cols_per_group
explode_cols = list(np.arange(nb_groups))
    
   
pd.concat([df.loc[:,:'objects'].reset_index(drop=True), \
    df.loc[:,'id':].set_axis(group_cols, axis=1).groupby(level=0, axis=1) \
      .apply(lambda x: x.values).to_frame().T.explode(explode_cols).reset_index(drop=True) \
      .rename(columns = lambda x: 'object_' + str(x)) \
          ], axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
   n  objects         object_0          object_1
0  0       41  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [17, 3, 3, 4, 5]
1  1       21  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [17, 3, 3, 4, 5]
2  2       36  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [17, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```